# Performance de requisição usando Html.BeginForm versus jQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Existe algum ganho de performance ao utilizar jQuery para realizar requições ajax em relação ao post utilizando Html.BeginForm?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Teste")
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
           @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Nome, new { @class = "form-control" })
        <span class="help-block">@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</span>
   }
   <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
         <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Enviar" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

Se for melhor fazer via requisição ajax, tem algum código de exemplo onde trate do ValidationSummary e ValidationMessageFor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A verdade é que não há relação nenhuma entre as duas práticas, por assim dizer.

O `Html.BeginForm()` é executado ainda no servidor, ele apenas ajuda - afinal, é um [HTML Helper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505244(v=vs.118).aspx) - a criar as tags `<form></form>`.

Já o jQuery, esse é executado no lado do client, no browser, bem depois do ciclo de vida do `BeginForm()` ter terminado.

Comment: A minha dúvida não é com relação ao HTML.BeginForm em si, mas à forma como a requisição é feita.

Comment: Isso é configurado nas duas maneiras. Mas ambos farão, como default, um HTTP POST Request. Então, no final, eles fazem exatamente a mesma coisa.